# Combinatorics problem : permutations of hats

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

here's the problem :

4 men enter a pub and let their hats in the cloakroom. When they go out, they randomly pick a hat.

1. What is the probability that exactly no-one get the right hat ? Let $A$ denote this event.
2. What is the probability that exactly 2 men get their right hats ? Let $B$ denote this event.

My attempt :

I numbered the hats from 1 to 4, and I know that there exists $4!=24$ possible permutations. I set my event set to be $$\Omega= \{ \omega_1,...,\omega_{24} \}, $$
where the $\omega_i$ are permutations of the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$. I then proceeded to count the events in which at least one number is at the right place (1 is in the first place or 2 is on the second place and so on). I got 15 possibilities :

$$\omega=(1,2,3,4),$$
$$ \omega=(1,2,4,3), $$
$$ \omega=(1,3,4,2), $$
$$...$$

Hence the probability of no-one getting the right hat would be $\mathbb{P}(A)=\frac{24-15}{24}=\frac{9}{24}=\frac{3}{8}$.
I am quite unhappy with this method and I am asking myself if there is a more elegant way to solve it.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, you have to enumerate the number of [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement): in general, by using the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), for $n$ men the probability is
$$p_0(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}.$$
As regards the second question, the probability that exactly $m$ men with $0\leq m\leq n$ get their right hats is therefore given by
$$p_m(n)=\frac{\binom{n}{m}(n-m)!p_0(n-m)}{n!}=\frac{p_0(n-m)}{m!}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I could figure out how to get the number of derangements $d_n$ :
$$ d_n = n! \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \frac{1}{k!}.$$
Do you agree that the probability that exactly $m<n$ men get their right hat is given by :
$$\frac{d_{n-m}}{n!}.$$

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say that the probability is given by
$$ \frac{ {n \choose m} d_{n-m}}{n!}. $$

Comment: @Alain Yes, this second formula is correct.